# getString method of result set in SQL, returns the last value even when cursor is after the last line

Tags: sql, resultset

I have a query which gives 5 lines output. I tried to iterate over the resultset using next method. After 5/more than 5 iterations, rs.next starts to give 0. But getString method always returns the last value, when cursor is after the last row.

Can anyone please help me to find how this is possible or if this is expected?

Thanks,
Mathi

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: "Stranger things have happened." Don't call a function when you know you shouldn't. It's just like Forrest Gump's box of chocolates . . .

Comment: _italic_ **bold** 
`String query = 'select name from students';
stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
print rs.next(); print rs.getString("name");
print rs.next(); print rs.getString("name");
print rs.next(); print rs.getString("name");
print rs.next(); print rs.getString("name");
print rs.next(); print rs.getString("name");
print rs.next(); print rs.getString("name");
print rs.next(); print rs.getString("name");`

The outout is:
_italic_ **bold**
`1
Smurfette
1
Gargamel
1
Patric
1
Azrael
1
Grace
0
Grace
0
Grace`